# Adding 3 drop down text values in jscalc.io

Tags: javascript, parsing

I created a simple calc with jscalc.io and I'm having trouble parsing values so I can add them.

I have played with a few variations of the following code but no luck.  My javascript knowledge is really limited, like this is the first time writing something in JS. :)

jscalc.io returned the following error for this code:TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'inputs.Age.value')

```
"'use strict';
var varAge = parseFloat(inputs.Age.value);
var varWeight = parseFloat(inputs.Weight.value);
var varGender = parseFloat(inputs.Gender.value);

return {

  total: varAge + varWeight + varGender

        };
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just going to preface this by saying that I've never used jscalc.io, but I looked at the example and it looks like you're supposed to use `inputs.Age` instead of `inputs.Age.value`. Also, if you make your inputs as Numbers, you don't need to use `parseFloat`. So your fixed code would look like this:

```
'use strict';
var varAge = inputs.Age;
var varWeight = inputs.Weight;
var varGender = inputs.Gender;

return {
    total: varAge + varWeight + varGender
};
```